# Why does my code throw a System.ArgumentException (Illegal characters in path)?

Tags: c#, exception, xmlwriter, argumentexception

I'm currently working on a small code editor. Right now, I'm in the process of developing a feature to create project files (XML). For this I have the following code so far:

```
    public void CreateProject(string path, string name)
        {
            char l = path.Last();
            char f = path.First();

            if (l == '\"' && f == '\"')
            {
                path.Replace("\"", "");
            }

            XmlWriter createProj = XmlWriter.Create(path + name);
            createProj.WriteStartElement(name);
 }
```

As a test I've tried to create the following project:

```
ProjectManager m = new ProjectManager();
m.CreateProject(@"C:\Users\Sample\Documents", "HelloWorld");
```

However, this caused the exception mentioned in the title. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Apart from the path not being what you expect it to be, I cannot see any illegal stuff. Maybe put an output of the path there, to see what it actually is.

Comment: Your example would not even compile. `String` has no `Last` and `First` methods. Please show actual code.

Comment: Also, there will be no double-quotes in your inputs to `CreateProject` here.

Comment: @jira This IS my actual code. https://imgur.com/a/t8GYB5e

Comment: I just added the folders.

Comment: @jira I suppose these are Linq methods, seems ok.

Comment: @Jonas_ : there is `Path.Combine()` which should be preferred to concatenate bits of path (and filenames) together. It will handle the 'slashes' for you.

Comment: Ah ok. Forget about Linq

Comment: The code you've posted doesn't produce the error you describe.

Comment: FYI, that method can be reduced to: `XmlWriter.Create(Path.Combine(path, name)).WriteStartElement(name);`. But don't you want to add a file extension to the project file?